# Eigenvalue bounds of a random graph with a clique

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, eigenvalues, random-graphs

I'm looking into this [paper](http://www.math.tau.ac.il/%7Enogaa/PDFS/clique3.pdf) and having some problems proving (ii) of proposition 2.1. I don't quite understand how the lemma is proved. I also read the original [paper](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF02579329.pdf) where the lemma comes from but there aren't many ideas on that. I'm still quite new to graph theory so any help would be much appreciated.